# Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angular, parsing, typescript

I've got an error while parsing my Json file which is valid on https://jsonlint.com/

```
@Injectable()
export class LightParserService{
  ITEMS_URL = "./lights.json";
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getItems(): Promise<Light[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.ITEMS_URL).toPromise()
    .then(resp  => {
        return resp.json() as Light[];
      });
    }
}
```

when I use my function in another component:

```
lights : Light[] = [];
getLights(): void{
      this.lightService.getItems().then(light => this.lights = light);
    }
```

On my website i've got: Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Does anyone know how to fix this? my JSON file is valid and my Light object contains valid fields so I don't understand.

Comment: check the response you get from the server. the < usually comes if you get back html content instead of json. So maybe the server returns something you did not expect.

Comment: To fix the "Uncaught (in promise)" problem, you should add a `.catch(…)` handler at the end of your promise chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`./lights.json` probably returned HTML instead of json, so your resp.json() fails. You can add `console.log(resp.text())` before the `return resp.json() as Light[];` line, so you can see the raw response (or you can simply loo it up in the dev tools networking tab)

Comment: thanks yeah I needed to put my json file to the assets folder else it gave me html instead of JSON.

Comment: probably because it was returning a 404 error page, you should check the status code after you get the file request response to catch problems like that